# Graphics g - Using paint, how do I make things erase?

Tags: java, applet, paint, keylistener

my paint method goes like this.

```
public void paint (Graphics g)
{      

    while (cardChosen != 'a');
    {
       g.drawImage (selectionBG, 0, 0, 1960, 677, null);
        g.drawImage (duelSGX, x_coordinate, y_coordinate, 483, 677, null);
        g.drawImage (Ultor, x_coordinate + 777, y_coordinate, 483, 677, null);
        g.drawImage (Seirin, x_coordinate + 777 * 2, y_coordinate, 483, 677, null);
        g.drawImage (Rowgen, x_coordinate + 777 * 3, y_coordinate, 483, 677, null);
        g.drawImage (Ronel, x_coordinate + 777 * 4, y_coordinate, 483, 677, null);
        g.drawImage (Ophelia, x_coordinate + 777 * 5, y_coordinate, 483, 677, null);
        g.drawImage (Narza, x_coordinate + 777 * 6, y_coordinate, 483, 677, null);
        g.drawImage (Michele, x_coordinate + 777 * 7, y_coordinate, 483, 677, null);
        g.drawImage (Maxwell, x_coordinate + 777 * 8, y_coordinate, 483, 677, null);
        g.drawImage (MageDEAN, x_coordinate + 777 * 9, y_coordinate, 483, 677, null);
        g.drawImage (Kuda, x_coordinate + 777 * 10, y_coordinate, 483, 677, null);
        g.drawImage (Gravion, x_coordinate + 777 * 11, y_coordinate, 483, 677, null);
    }

}
```

I also have this.

```
    if (ev.getKeyCode () == KeyEvent.VK_A)
    cardChosen = 'a';

    repaint ();
```

Now considering this shouldn't every thing I paint in pain disappear when I press 'a' and appear when I let go?
It doesn't. The picture shows, up and it lags.

Comment: You can change Title to "Graphics g - Using paint, how do I make things erase?" to make it more readable

Answer (score 1):

Your paint(...) method should be:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g); // to clear the background

    // add your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got dangerous code: you've got a `while (true)` loop within a painting method, and this will grind the GUI to an ignominious halt. Never do that. Instead

- Use Swing and draw within a JPanel or JCompnent's `paintComponent(...)` method.
- Be sure to call the super's `paintComponent(...)` method. Often this should be the first line of your paintComponent method override, and this will erase the old images.
- Most important, get all program logic, like that while loop, **out** of all painting methods. All painting methods must be as blindingly fast as possible, and so you never want code in there that could be called elsewhere and that could possibly slow it down. Also you never have full control over if or when the painting methods are called, and so program logic might falter if present within these methods.
- Better would be to have an `if (...)` block of some type within the paintComponent method, and then change the state of this block in an event listener, then call `repaint()`.
- The while shouldn't be in your code regardless, since yours is an event driven program. Instead listen for events, and then respond.